# How do I design a Notification/Push Service in a decentralized cluster?

Tags: cassandra, notifications, push, distributed, centralized

It's not easy to design a notification/push service for a decentralized (peer-to-peer) cluster. For example, if I want Cassandra to push out a notification to Service *A*, if one table field has changed its value by Service *B*, that's not easy. This is because Cassandra is organized in a decentralized manner, e.g., 5 nodes, and they don't know when a quorum of three nodes are committed before pushing the change to *A*. However, in a centralized (master-slave) cluster, things are different. ZooKeeper, for example, knows when 3 nodes out of the 5 are committed, and a notification service can be arranged.

How can we design such a push service in a decentralized cluster?

One obvious solution would be waiting for a certain period of time (say, 10 seconds) and notify *B* regardless.

Another option: If Service *B* has received 3 acks from Cassandra that the quorum has been satisfied, *B* then would send out the notification to *A* instead of Cassandra itself sending it.

Are there any other decent solutions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Cassandra **consistency level**. It's like waiting some period of time, but this way you are sure to have the right data.

With a small example:

**Write**

Imagine you have a **RF** of 3, then on the write, if you put a consistency level of 3, you need the answer of 3 computers (that write the data) to validate a write which make it consistent.

**READ**

You can set this argument to **all**, but the greater the required count, the slower it will be. I think as many machines as the RF is fine, so you can compare all timestamp from the different replicas.

There are some predefined consistency levels. To have a better understanding of this, read the following documentation:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html

This mechanism slows Cassandra, because Cassandra is not made to be consistent, but instead to be available. If you want consistency, look at **HBase** or **MongoDB**.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is Change Data Capture, which will be released in a future version of Cassandra.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8844